# "Error: No peer certificate" in Ubuntu One Android app

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, downloads

Downloading and (automatic) uploading in the Ubuntu One Android app stopped working all of a sudden. The upload of other files also doesn't seem to work. It keeps saying: "Error: No peer certificate".

Logging in and seeing filelists works fine.

I use an Android 2.3 phone.

Tried rebooting, reinstalling the app and logging out and in of the app.

What should I do?

Comment: I just ran in to this bug while reinstalling a ROM. Hopefully it's just a temporary outage. +1 and I'll check this in the morning...

Comment: +1
and download through the web site doesn't work too

Comment: Problem with the app has been happening for a couple of days in a row now.

Answer (score 2):

We had intermittent issues with the server that is responsible for receiving/sending files, between 7th and 9th of October. The issue should be gone by know.